# How can we get list of non-system users on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

Considering that all users with `id >= 1000` are non-system users, how can we get list of these users in a single command?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @m.s., this question is tagged [bash] and [shell], and is not unusual or inappropriate for SO questions bearing those tags.  "What command to use to do X" *is* a programming question for `bash`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to get all users whose `gid` is greater than or equals 1000. Use this command for that:

```
awk -F: '($3>=1000)&&($1!="nobody"){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

If you want system users (gid<1000) it will be:

```
awk -F: '($3<1000){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - `libvirt-qemu` is installed with a GID of 64055. I left an answer which shows how to ignore system users like `libvirt-qemu`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62051801/530160

Answer (score 7):

You can use `awk` for this task:

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000' /etc/passwd
```

This will split the `/etc/passwd` file by colon, then if field 3 (userid) is greater than or equal to 1000, it will print the entire `/etc/passwd` record.

If you want to get only the username out of this list then:

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Where $1 is the first field of `etc/passwd` which is the username.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the system recognizes only local users (i.e. those recorded in `/etc/passwd`, as opposed to any authenticated via a remote service such as LDAP, NIS, or Winbind), you can use `grep`, `sed`, or `awk` to extract the data from `/etc/passwd`.  `awk` is the most flexible of those, but how about a solution with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^\([^:]\+\):[^:]\+:[1-9][0-9]\{3\}/ { s/:.*//; p }' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

System users (should be) those listed in `/etc/passwd` with UIDs less than 1000.  The actual number is a convention only. Non-system users need not be listed there.  You can get the list using [getent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html) and [awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/awk.html) ignoring ["nobody"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186568/what-is-nobody-nobody-user-and-group) (also a convention):

```
getent passwd |awk -F : '$3 >= 1000 && $3 < 65534'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to ignore GIDs less than 1000, but also GIDs greater than 60000. Ubuntu/Debian reserve these for various system services.

```
awk -F: '($3>=1000)&&($3<60000)&&($1!="nobody"){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for doing this on *all* your machines, using Ansible and `awk`, building on [JNevill's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221001/jnevill) answer:

```
ansible -i inventories/cd_staging all -m shell -a "awk -F: '\$3 >= 1000 && \$7 \!~ /nologin/ {print \$1}' \/etc\/passwd |sort"
```