# shell script user admin program

Tags: bash, shell, shebang

I am writing a bash script to add edit and remove users. I cannot get it to work. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I have added the .sh files into the designated folder by creating empty documents saved with .sh. When i type in options 1 or 2 it just asks me to enter an option again whilst option 3 reads ERROR.
This is my upgraded code
Problem is that I cannot create a file still

Main menu code

```
#!/bin/bash
trap ''2
title="////////////////////
10101010101010101010
///main user menu///
10101010101010101010
////////////////////
"
clear
echo "$title"

PS3='Select option: '
choice=("Create User" "Edit User" "Remove User" "Exit")
select cho in "${choice[@]}"
do
    case $cho in
        "Create User")
            /home/hiphappy1/Documents/Courseworkfiles/Users.sh
            ;;
        "Edit User")
            /home/hiphappy1/Documents/Courseworkfiles/EditUser.sh
            ;;
        "Remove User")
            /home/hiphappy1/Documents/Courseworkfiles/RemoveUser.sh
            ;;
        "Exit")
            exit 0
            ;;
        *) echo "ERROR try again"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

add user code

```
#!/bin/bash
title="////////////////////////
101010101010101010101010
//Create Multiple Users//
101010101010101010101010
////////////////////////
"
clear
echo "$title"
password="ArsenalRule"
for USERNAME in $(cat /home/hiphappy1/Documents/Courseworkfiles/Userlist.txt)
do
    useradd $USERNAME -m –s /bin/bash
    echo -e "${password}\n${password}"! | passwd $USERNAME
done
read -r -p "Return to menu? [Y/N] " response
case $response in
    [yY])
        /home/hiphappy1/Documents/Courseworkfiles/Menulist.sh
        ;;
    [nN])
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        echo "ERROR try again"
        ;;
esac
exit
```

edit user code

```
#!/bin/bash
title2="//////////////////
10101010101010101010
/////Edit User//////
10101010101010101010
////////////////////
"
clear
echo "$title2"
echo "Enter username:"
read username
echo""

id $username &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$username exists... changing Password."
else
    echo "$username does not exist! Password was not changed for $username"
    exit 0
fi

passwd $username
read -r -p "Return to menu? [Y/N] " response
case $response in
    [yY])
        /home/hiphappy1/Documents/Courseworkfiles/Menulist.sh
        ;;
    [nN])
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        echo "ERROR try again"
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

remove user code

```
#!/bin/bash
title="///////////////////
10101010101010101010
////Remove User/////
10101010101010101010
////////////////////
"
clear
echo "$title"
echo -e "Users: "
cat /etc/passwd | grep “[1][0-9][0-9][0-9]” | cut -d “:” -f1
echo ""
echo -e "Select user to remove: "
read username
sudo deluser --remove-home $username
echo ""
echo " Removing"
sleep 2
echo ""
echo " $username REMOVED"
read -r -p "Return to menu? [Y/N] " response
case $response in
    [yY])
        /home/hiphappy1/Documents/CourseworkFiles/Menulist.sh
        ;;
    [nN])
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        echo "ERROR try again"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Your main menu code, `choice=("Create User" "Edit User" "Remove User" "Exit")` but your case statement is looking for "Delete User".

Comment: Can you also clarify the contents of each file?  e.g. Your menu executes `/home/hiphappy1/Documents/Courseworkfiles/Users.sh` to "Create User", but your create user code seems to read itself...? `for USERNAME in $(cat /home/hiphappy1/Documents/Courseworkfiles/Users.sh)`
Make sure you use lowercase variables for your local variables, especially as the USERNAME variable is used by bash as an environment variable

Comment: Make sure your double quotes are actually double quotes (`"`), not Window's double quotes (`“”`).

Comment: Your regular expression in grep in your "remove user code" is missing a `[`.  See ["get all users whose gid is greater than or equals 1000"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33150591/7851272)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Didn't notice that I had written Delete instead of remove. Good spot. And the missing [. The smallest things seem to be invisible. I've managed to connect the menu to the methods now. But I'm still struggling to add users. It just says return to menu Y/N.

Comment: Check `/etc/passwd` to see if your new user exists.  I don't think `useradd` confirms when the user is created so you might find it actually works.

Comment: I changed the cat line to :- for USERNAME in $(cat /home/hiphappy1/Documents/Courseworkfiles/Userlist.txt) to put new users into a text file as i should have before. But still having the same problem with create file option going straight to return to menu without allowing to enter any users

Comment: OK got the menu working properly. The quotes were wrong on two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Had to write this bit in an answer as it requires a more detailed example and is a general design consideration for calling other executables.

In your sub-menus, you ask if you would like to return to the main menu.  You should not be making a call back to `Menu.sh` because you are adding another layer or sub-process.  Instead, you should allow e.g. `CreateMenu.sh` to just exit normally which will flow back into `Menu.sh`, at which point you `break` from the `select` loop and come back in at the top using a `while` loop to display the menu again.  Here is the code:

Menu.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
trap ''2
title="////////////////////
10101010101010101010
///main user menu///
10101010101010101010
////////////////////
"
clear
echo "$title"
courseworkfiles="/home/hiphappy1/Documents/CourseworkFiles"
PS3='Select option: '
choice=("Create User" "Edit User" "Remove User" "Exit")
finished=0
while (( !finished )); do
    select cho in "${choice[@]}"
    do
        case $cho in
            "Create User")
                "$courseworkfiles/CreateUser.sh"
                break
                ;;
            "Edit User")
                "$courseworkfiles/EditUser.sh"
                break
                ;;
            "Delete User")
                "$courseworkfiles/RemoveUser.sh"
                break
                ;;
            "Exit")
                finished=1
                break
                ;;
            *)
                echo "ERROR try again"
                ;;
        esac
    done
done
```

CreateUser.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...code to create user...
# 
# ..echo some sort of confirmation message
#
# then do nothing, no read, no case, just let if flow back to Menu.sh
```

Comment: Sorry, I got lazy in the `CreateUser.sh` bit, but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Also, I had missed a `break` which stopped `Menu.sh` from exiting.  This is now added.

Comment: Your kidding? Your help has been greatly appreciated. I've gone from my menu not even joining up together to a few smaller issues. I think I am nearly there.

Comment: @NeilPettifer Glad it's been helpful.  When you say that you "cannot create a file still", what file are you trying to create and how?  At the moment, it looks like you are reading `Userlist.txt`, creating a new user for each in that file, then exiting.

Comment: I can't work out how to add the user. I want to add user using the program and then it needs to be saved for later use. I tried adding to .sh which wasn't working and then i thought that maybe i could save it into a text file instead.

Comment: The `useradd` command creates a user on your linux system.  This user can be found again using the command `getent passwd [username]` where [username] is the username you want the information for.  Why do you need to save it to Userlist.txt?

Comment: where you put the link should i change the whole cat etc/passwd line to what you suggested instead? awk -F: '($3<1000){print $1}' /etc/passwd

Comment: so i can show that the users entered on this program have been successfully saved to the system.

Comment: @NeilPettifer, `awk -F: '($3>=1000)&&($1!="nobody"){print $1}' /etc/passwd` would be the correct thing to use, but make sure you don't pass them all to `useradd` again.  Look into `getent passwd` and users' "finger" information.  Perhaps, when you create a user, you could put a marker in one of the "phone number" fields which, from my experience, are never used.  You could use this to differentiate between users your program has created, and users which have been created outised of your program.